# Using zip to step through two lists in tandem is throwing can't call unicode error

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using zip() to step through two lists just the way it shows in the python manual (5.6, Looping Techniques)

```
pg_lst = getCSVData(pjoin(wkgdir, pg_fil_nm))
for out_row, pg_row in zip(outputdata, pg_lst):
    # if the account numbers match
    if out_row[0] == pg_row[0]:
        # append the balance to the output row
        out_row.append(pg_row[2])
    else:
        # report unexpected account # deviation
        print 'mismatch out: %s, pg: %s' % (out_row[0], pg_row[0])
```

but as soon as it reaches my for statement, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
   File "Z:\AfterTheFall\ATF.py", line 120, in (module)
     for out_row, pg_row in zip(outputdata, pg_lst):
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

The only difference I can see between my code and the example in the manual

```
>>> questions = ['name', 'quest', 'favorite color']
>>> answers = ['lancelot', 'the holy grail', 'blue']
>>> for q, a in zip(questions, answers):
...     print 'What is your {0}?  It is {1}.'.format(q, a)
```

Is that my lists contain further lists, rather than singleton elements.  Does zip() not work on compound lists?

Comment: I think you have a variable named zip that is shadowing the zip method ....

Answer (score 0):

As @Joran Beasley suggested, I looked for a variable named 'zip' in the program. I did have such a variable handling zip codes.  I changed it to `zip_code`, and the zip function worked correctly.